# (.Net 6) How to use OAuth 2 Azure AD to authenticate and Send email (With no prompt consent)

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

Guys I am trying to use a specific user to log in on Azure Add using Identity.Client and MailKit.

I am using this service in both projects (Web App and Console App).
It's prompted the consent all the time I need to remove the consent for the final user.

What can I do to get this working?

I have my application on Azure:

[image]

Authentication:

[image]

Certificates and secrets:

[image]

API permissions:
[image]

.Net 6 Code

```cs
    private async Task<IPublicClientApplication> CreateClientApp()
{

    var urlNoConsent = _config.GetSection("AzureAd:UrlNoConsent").Get<string>();

    var options = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
    {
        ClientId = _config.GetSection("AzureAd:ClientId").Get<string>(),
        TenantId = _config.GetSection("AzureAd:TenantId").Get<string>(),
        RedirectUri = _config.GetSection("AzureAd:RedirectUri").Get<string>()
    };

    var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .CreateWithApplicationOptions(options)
        .Build();

    _logger.LogInformation("Trying AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth");

    return app;

}

            
private async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetAzureAuthenticationToken(IPublicClientApplication app)
{
            
    var tenantId = _config.GetSection("AzureAd:TenantId").Get<string>();
    var scopes = _config.GetSection("AzureAd:Scopes").Get<string[]>();
    var urlNoConsent = _config.GetSection("AzureAd:UrlNoConsent").Get<string>();
    var prompt = Prompt.NoPrompt;

    AuthenticationResult authToken = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithPrompt(prompt).ExecuteAsync();

    _logger.LogInformation("authResult.AccessToken = {0}", authToken.AccessToken);
    
    return authToken;         
}

public async Task<bool> SendEmail(string toEmail, string subject, string emailBody, bool ccAdmin = false)
{
                    
    var app = await this.CreateClientApp();

    var authNewToken = await this.GetAzureAuthenticationToken(app);
    var authToken = await this.RefreshAzureAuthenticationToken(authNewToken, app);
    

    string senderEmail = _config["AzureAd:EmailFrom"];

    using var client = new SMTPClient();

    client.Connect("smtp.office365.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);

    var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(authToken.Account.Username, authToken.AccessToken);
    client.Authenticate(oauth2);

    AlternateView avBody = await this.SetImagesLayout(emailBody);

    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(senderEmail);
    mailMessage.To.Add(toEmail);
    mailMessage.Subject = subject;
    mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(avBody);

    if (ccAdmin)
    {
        var users = await this.GetAdministrators("Administrator");

        string[] emails = users.Select(x => x.Email).ToArray();
        foreach (var email in emails)
        {
            mailMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress(email)); //Adding CC email Id  
        }
    }
    //mailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(bcc));  //Adding BCC email Id 

    var mime = (MimeMessage)mailMessage;
    mime.WriteTo(@"c:\temp\mime-mm.eml");

    client.Send(mime);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the user consent like below.
Go to your application from the ***enterprise applications***,

[image]

Then select option  Do not allow user consent
But note that administrator must give admin consent

[image]

***Then if the admin consent is given , the user wont get any consent screen after admin approval.***

[image]

---

**Edit:**

From the enterprise applications ***select your application and see user consent tab in permissions tab Under security.***

[image]

Remove the consent through powershell command below or through the graph api:

```
 #Get that user or service principal using object Id
$ServicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $AzureAdServicePrincipalObjectId
 
# Get list of all of the  delegated permissions for that service principal
$spOAuth2PermissionsGrants = Get-AzureADOAuth2PermissionGrant -All $true| Where-Object { $_.clientId -eq $ServicePrincipal.ObjectId }
 
# To remove the  consented permissions for that  particular service principal
$spOAuth2PermissionsGrants | Where-Object PrincipalId -eq $UserPrincipalObjectId | Remove-AzureADOAuth2PermissionGrant
```

Reference : [remove azureadoauth2permissiongrant |  Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/remove-azureadoauth2permissiongrant?view=azureadps-2.0)

Comment: I tried and it keeps prompting the user consent!

Comment: Please check the latest edit